# Google Apps Script HTML style not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, html-email

I'm trying to style my HTML file to output a grid with tiles layout. But it seems that the MailApp is not rendering it correctly. Can anyone tell me what is wrong on the code?

I've tried to write the HTML file with inline styling but it did not work out. I've tried adding the
`.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)` method but it did not work out.

## Code.gs

```js
function createEmail() {
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test')

  var message = templ.evaluate().setTitle('Weekly Performance Review').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).getContent();

  Logger.log(message)
  var email = "email@domain.com";
  Logger.log("email@domain.com");
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Weekly Performance Review ",
    htmlBody: message
})

}
```

## File test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <style>
    .app {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      /*   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px); */
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
      /*   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr) 150px); */
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app"
    style="display: grid; grid-gap: 50px; overflow: hidden; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr)); grid-auto-flow: dense;">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
    <div class="item">item 7</div>
    <div class="item">item 8</div>
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
    <div class="item">item 10</div>
    <div class="item">item 11</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Output email body

[image: Output Email Body]

Also, I have not been able to add a style tag and render it, I do not know very much about styling or html, could someone explain?

**I was expecting something like this**

[image: Grid Layout]

Thanks

Comment: Its best to use tables and have CSS inline at the td level. Not all email clients read div's the same way

Answer (score 1):

MailApp hasn't a sendEmail method able to handle "correctly" an object as the first parameter.

Instead of

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Weekly Performance Review ",
    htmlBody: message
})
```

use

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
    email,
    "Weekly Performance Review ",
    {htmlBody: message}
)
```

or

```
GmailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Weekly Performance Review ",
    htmlBody: message
})
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options